# Парсинг на Python НЕ css

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

Мне необходимо спарсить категории товаров и товары с их URL. на сайте защит нет никакой. Проблема собственно в том, что я не могу структурированно спарсить данные, так как все называется одинаково. Это только часть странички кода...Есть подозрение, что парсить нужно не по css...

```html
<li><a href="/shop/532/Smartphones-Tablets">Smartphones l Tablets</a><span><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></span>
                    <ul class="set_bg1">
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Smartphones</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href=ссылка">Samsung</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Vivo</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Realme</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Oppo</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Xiaomi</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Wiko</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Infinix</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Tecno</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Huawei</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Nokia</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Lava</a></li>
                      <li class="col2" style="margin-top: -20.6em;"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Tablets</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Huawei</a></li>
                      <!--<li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Acer</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Asus</a></li>-->
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Lenovo</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Samsung</a></li>
                      <li class="col3" style="margin-top: -6.8em;"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Accessories</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">Power banks</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">Adapters/Data Cables</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">Micro SD Card</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">USB On The Go (OTG)</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">Others</a></li>
                      <li class="imgback" style="margin-top: -10.2em;"><img src="ссылка" border="0"/></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <!--------- 2. computer------------------------------------------------>
                  <li><a href="ссылка">Computers | Notebooks</a><span><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></span>
                    <ul class="set_bg1" style="margin-top: -32.7px;">
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Notebooks</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Acer </a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Asus</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href=ссылка">Dell</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">HP</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Lenovo </a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">MSI</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка">Notebook Case</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Printers</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Toners</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Scanners</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Projector</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка"  class="subject">Peripheral/Data Cable</a></li>
                      <li class="col1"><a href="ссылка"  class="subject">Power Supplies/Changers</a></li>
                      <li class="col2" style="margin-top: -23.8em;"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">PC/Cases</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Acer</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Asus</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Dell</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">HP</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Lenovo</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">All-in-one</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Acer</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Asus</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Dell</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">HP</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Lenovo</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Mini Pc / Stick Pc</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Asus</a></li>
                      <li class="col2"><a href="ссылка">Intel</a></li>
                      <li class="col3" style="margin-top: -25.5em;"><a href="ссылка" class="subject">Monitors</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">Acer</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">AOC</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">Asus</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">BenQ</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">Dell</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">HP</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href=ссылка">Lenovo</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">LG</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">Philips</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">Samsung</a></li>
                      <li class="col3"><a href="ссылка">MSI</a></li>
                      <li class="imgback" style="margin-top: -18.7em;"><img src="ссылка" border="0"/></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
```

https://www.tohome.com/index.aspx ссылка на страницу

Comment: Спарсите перебором дочерних элементов

Comment: Вообще было бы неплохо привести полный код страницы и Ваши попытки парсинга. Фрагмент кода в вопросе не является валидным HTML. Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы быть уверенным, что все ниженаписанное корректно отработает на полной версии данных нужно иметь хотя-бы ссылку на ресурс, но на представленном обрывке, нижеприведенный код выполняет поставленную задачу

```py
import json
from itertools import takewhile
from typing import Dict, List

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4.element import Tag, PageElement

soup = Soup(open('data.html', encoding='utf-8'), 'html.parser')


def parse_section(elem: Tag):
    for a in takewhile(
            lambda x: x.get('class') != ['subject'],
            elem.find_all_next('a')
    ):
        yield a.get_text(strip=True)


result: Dict[str, Dict[str, list]] = dict()

for item in soup.find_all('i', class_='fa fa-caret-right'):
    section = item.find_next('ul')
    header = item.find_previous('a').string

    section_name = header.get_text(strip=True)

    result.setdefault(section_name, dict())

    for sub in section.find_all('a', class_='subject'):
        subsection_name = sub.get_text(strip=True)
        for i in parse_section(sub):
            result[section_name][subsection_name] = result[section_name].setdefault(subsection_name, []) + [i]

json.dump(
    result,
    open('result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8'),
    ensure_ascii=False,
    indent=2
)
```

Содержимое файла `result.json`

```json
{
  "Smartphones l Tablets": {
    "Smartphones": [
      "Samsung",
      "Vivo",
      "Realme",
      "Oppo",
      "Xiaomi",
      "Wiko",
      "Infinix",
      "Tecno",
      "Huawei",
      "Nokia",
      "Lava"
    ],
    "Tablets": [
      "Huawei",
      "Lenovo",
      "Samsung"
    ],
    "Accessories": [
      "Power banks",
      "Adapters/Data Cables",
      "Micro SD Card",
      "USB On The Go (OTG)",
      "Others",
      "Computers | Notebooks"
    ]
  },
  "Computers | Notebooks": {
    "Notebooks": [
      "Acer",
      "Asus",
      "Dell",
      "HP",
      "Lenovo",
      "MSI",
      "Notebook Case"
    ],
    "PC/Cases": [
      "Acer",
      "Asus",
      "Dell",
      "HP",
      "Lenovo"
    ],
    "All-in-one": [
      "Acer",
      "Asus",
      "Dell",
      "HP",
      "Lenovo"
    ],
    "Mini Pc / Stick Pc": [
      "Asus",
      "Intel"
    ],
    "Monitors": [
      "Acer",
      "AOC",
      "Asus",
      "BenQ",
      "Dell",
      "HP",
      "Lenovo",
      "LG",
      "Philips",
      "Samsung",
      "MSI"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: брат, напиши мне в телеге плз @bizzare_gg